# Small Speaker with High dB. Loud enough?

Tags: audio, components, component-selection

I need a compact speaker suitable for a 16mm diameter tubular enclosure. The speaker must be capable of playing voice audio clips with sufficient clarity and volume to be easily hearable and understandable for 1-2m away in a small room. I'm thinking about 30% of a modern iPhones volume level would be fine.

I'm looking at CUI Devices speakers page, they have [good filters](https://www.cuidevices.com/catalog/audio/speakers?q=3Uv9-0cP0dM0fR0hZa3Wv9-0cP0dj0dM0fq0fR0g_0hZ0uL0JE0JK0Mx) for width/height and tons of options that physically fit.

I think I might have found a possibility: CMS-151125-076L100B

- 15 x 11mm
- S.P. Level (dB): 92.5 (0.7 W / 1 m)
- [Product page (links to data sheet)](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/audio/speakers/miniature-(10-mm%7E40-mm)/cms-151125-076l100a)

I'm worried though, is this as loud as I think it might be / how loud will it be? Maybe I'm missing something? It's pretty tiny.

According to some [random Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-loud-can-an-iPhone-play-music-in-decibels) from 5y ago about iPhone volume: *"I have read that one can get up to 85–90 db at 0.5 meters"*. (an iPhone) So if this answer is accurate, then it should be relatively loud and meet my requirements as it?

Is a speaker like this even capable of playing voice clips?

Comment: It's got an acoustic bandwidth of 700 Hz to about 15 kHz. Will that correspond to meeting your requirements? It's definitely not close to poor hi-fi. For loudness, read the data sheet. The numbers are there and clear.

Comment: I read the data sheet fully and researched, and came to the conclusion it will be loud enough, but I'm not confident in that conclusion at all hence asking here. As for the range, yes that covers the sounds I need it to cover (human voice talking) ~ more curious about if it will it be loud enough?

Comment: The SPL levels are quoted in the data sheet. They don't correspond with what you write in your question (some random quora answer) i.e. stick to getting facts from the data sheet and notice the distance at which the SPL levels were made. But, to cut a long story short, nobody but you can tell so, why not buy one and test it. Sometimes, that's the best option and sometimes it's the only credible option, The supplier (CUI) is reputable and I've talked with their designers in the past so I know they are OK. However, and disappointingly their data sheet disagrees with the web page.

Comment: Thanks yeah I'll get one and report an answer back here in the future. Just a bit pricey for me to order so wanted to see if somebody could answer beforehand! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only do care about understandability of the voice and not some other voice characteristics and your environment is not particularly noisy, 85-90dB are way above the pleasant sound level and will probably scare the hell of an unexpecting user. The normal human talking is 50-60dB and this is ~1000 times less power than 90dB.

In practice, if you throw 10-100mW at whatever speaker you dig from the junk bin, you will get enough sound level to recognize speech. This is the power level most people listen to radio at in small and more or less quiet rooms.

You may want to limit the bandwidth of the signal to e.g. 300-3000Hz just like older phone systems do in order to get good recognition vs distortion and used power.